# Cycle detection in a undirected graph

Tags: java, depth-first-search

I am trying to detect if there is any cycle or not in a undirected graph. I am trying to solve this in dfs approach.My logic is For every visited vertex ‘v’, if there is an adjacent ‘u’ such that u is already visited and u is not the parent of v, then there is a cycle in the graph. If i don't find such an adjacent for any vertex, i can say that there is no cycle. here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CheckCycle {

    public static int nodeno;
    public static int Matrix[][];
    public static boolean Visited[];
    //public static boolean hascycle=false;
    public static int path[]=new int[50];

    public static boolean returncycle(){
        for(int i=0;i<nodeno;i++)
        {
            if(!Visited[i])
               if( dfstocheck(i,-1))
                   return true;
        }

        return  false;
    }
    public static boolean dfstocheck(int v,int parent){
        Visited[v]=true;
        for(int i=0;i<nodeno;i++) {
            if (Matrix[v][i] == 1 && !Visited[i]) {
                return (dfstocheck(i, v)) ;

            }
            else if (i != parent)
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            nodeno = in.nextInt();


            Matrix = new int[nodeno][nodeno];
            Visited = new boolean[nodeno];

            Matrix = new int[nodeno][nodeno];
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeno; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < nodeno; j++) {
                    Matrix[i][j] = in.nextInt();
                }
            }
            if(returncycle)
                System.out.println("Contain cycle");
            else
                System.out.println("no cycle");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is what ever adjacency matrix i give input it returns no cycle. suppose for node no `5` 1st matrix should return cycle and 2nd one should return no cycle.

```
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 0

0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
```

I just cant find bug in my implementation. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't see where you change your ```hascycle```.

Comment: To expand on zhh - you need to have `hascycle = returncycle();` somewhere in your main method.

Comment: _"and u is not the parent of v"_ - this seems redundant.  With this condition you allow cycles between two nodes.  Also, "parent" has no meaning in a general graph, nodes have predecessors and successors.

Comment: I have edited my code according to your instruction. But now it always returns "contain cycle" @ErwinBolwidt

Comment: Your code isn't very readable. You need to chose names for methods and variables that reflect purpose.  But I believe this is wrong: `if (dfstocheck(i, v)) { return true; }`.  You probably want `return dfstocheck(i, v);`

Comment: after this change, the result remains same @Gene

Comment: I didn't say it was the only problem. You need to trace the program's execution by hand, with added `writeln`s, or in a debugger and determine where what the program is _actually_ doing diverges from what you _think_ it's doing. That's the essence of debugging. Asking others to debug your program is no way to learn.